# Matplotlib: Customizing Date Tick Labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to do some plots in Matplotlib. While I am able to figure out a lot of things, there are some things which are not working as I would hope. For example, in the code below I am plotting three charts. In the final monthly chart I am trying to put the Major Tick and gridline every Quarter (so March, June, Sep, Dec of every year) and minor tick/gridline every month. While the minor is coming out correct the major is not.
Similarly, in the 2nd plot (The Weekly Plot), I want the major ticks/gridlines every month and minor every week. Again, the minor seems to work , but not the major.
I also want to format the x-axis date to be in the format Mar-2015. But it keeps coming as '2015-03'
How do I fix this?
some extract of the code is below. I can edit to post complete code if it helps

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import itertools

import random
random.seed(30)
np.random.seed(30)

first_names=('John','mary','hillary')
last_names=('Johnson','Smith','Williams')

start_date,end_date = '1/1/2015','12/31/2018'
date_rng = pd.date_range(start= start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
length_of_field = date_rng.shape[0]

group_3 = [random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names) for _ in range(length_of_field)]

df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['user'] = group_3
df['attempts'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['n_date'] = df['date'].dt.normalize()

df_grp_1 = df.groupby(['user']).sum()
df_grp_1.sort_values(by=['attempts'],ascending=False,inplace=True)

toppers = list(df_grp_1.index.array)
toppers_to_keep =toppers[:6]

agg_df_daily = df.pivot_table(index='n_date',columns = 'user',values='attempts',aggfunc='sum')
print('\n(agg_df_daily:)')
print(agg_df_daily)

agg_df_weekly = agg_df_daily[toppers_to_keep].resample('W').sum()
print('\n(agg_df_weekly:)')
print(agg_df_weekly)

agg_df_monthly = agg_df_daily[toppers_to_keep].resample('M').sum()
print('\n(agg_df_monthly:)')
print(agg_df_monthly)

# PLOTTING...

topper_case =[x.title() for x in toppers_to_keep]
start, end = start_date,end_date
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10.0,7.5)  #set figure size
marker = itertools.cycle(('*','o','+',','))
years = mdates.YearLocator()
quarters = mdates.MonthLocator(3,6,9,12)
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
weekly = mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),interval=1)

fig = plt.figure()
st = fig.suptitle("Number of Attempts DAILY", fontsize="x-large")

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
for i in range(0,3):
    ax1.plot(agg_df_daily.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i],marker='.')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(quarters)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_title("Top 4 Users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attempts per Day')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2,sharex=ax1)
for i in range(3,6):
    plt.plot(agg_df_daily.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i])
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_title("Next 4  users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attempts per Day')
plt.xlabel('Day')

# WEEKLY PLOT
fig = plt.figure()
st = fig.suptitle("Number of Attempt Over Time By 8 Most Prolific Users WEEKLY", fontsize="x-large")

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
for i in range(0,3):
    plt.plot(agg_df_weekly.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i],marker='.')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(weekly)
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_title("Top 4 Most Prolific Users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attempts per Week')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2,sharex=ax1)
for i in range(3,6):
    plt.plot(agg_df_weekly.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i])
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_title("Next 4 Most Prolific Users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attempts per Week')
plt.xlabel('Week')

# MONTHLY PLOT
fig = plt.figure()
st = fig.suptitle("Number of Attempts Over Time By 8 Most Prolific Users MONTHLY", fontsize="x-large")

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
for i in range(0,3):
    ax1.plot(agg_df_monthly.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i],marker='.')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(quarters)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b\n%Y'))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_title("Top 4 Most Prolific Users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attemps per Month')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2,sharex=ax1)
for i in range(3,6):
    plt.plot(agg_df_monthly.loc[start:end,toppers[i]],label=topper_case[i],marker='o')
ax2.legend()
ax2.set_title("Next 4 Most Prolific Users")
plt.grid(True,linestyle='--')
plt.ylabel('Number of Attempts per Month')
plt.xlabel('Month')

plt.show()
```

Comment: let me modify the quesiton and add the complete code

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have added the complete code

Comment: I see. The problem is that at the moment you add a shared axes, that axes' locators and formatters are imposed on all the shared axes. So the initial ticker is overwritten. You will hence need to set the ticker after the sharing (and then it will not matter to which of the two shared axes).

Comment: hmm. that is odd. becuase it is picking up the minor_locator it seems. so instead of doing it with ax1. i need to do it with ax2? I thought that since ax2 was referring to ax1, all things in ax1 will flow through into ax2

Comment: As said, you can use any axes, the important bit is to *first* create the sharing, then set the ticker. This may, after all, be considered as a bug, but for now this is how it works.

Comment: Just as a hint, `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)` gets around some of these awkwardnesses.

Comment: I moved the line: ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2,sharex=ax1)    to be just after the line: ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1). But it did not help